# How to use OR condition in a JavaScript IF statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean-expression

I understand that in JavaScript you can write:

```
if (A && B) { do something }
```

But how do I implement an OR such as:

```
if (A OR B) { do something }
```

Answer (score 326, accepted):

Use [the logical "OR" operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR), that is `||`.

```
if (A || B)
```

Note that if you use string comparisons in the conditions, you need to perform a comparison for *each* condition:

```
if ( var1 == "A" || var1 == "B" )
```

If you only do it in the first one, then it will always return true:

```
if ( var1 == "A" || "B" ) //don't do this; it is equivalent to if ("B"), which is always true
```

The official ECMAScript documentation can be found [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#prod-LogicalORExpression)

Answer (score 102):

Worth noting that `||` will also return `true` if BOTH `A` and `B` are `true`.

In JavaScript, if you're looking for `A` or `B`, *but not both*, you'll need to do something similar to:

```
if( (A && !B) || (B && !A) ) { ... }
```

Comment: Shouldn't be first phrase be "Worth noting that || will return true if EITHER var A OR var B is true" ??  It implies what you mentioned is (true | true) = true. which is common and understood.

Comment: (A && !B) || (B && !A) **can be replaced with** A ^ B which is much smoother

Comment: @Murplyx: In most cases yes, but numbers outside the 32 bit range can fail. `(Math.pow(2,32)-1) ^ 0; // -1 (success)` ... `Math.pow(2,32) ^ 0; // 0 (failure)`

Comment: `if (A ? !B : B) {...` would be a shorter substitute that wouldn't have the 32-bit limitation. Or maybe `if (!A != !B) {...`

Comment: @squint Why would a true or false ever be outside of the 32 bit range hence they are only 0 or 1, and btw if you compare numbers just use !!n to get the boolean value.

Comment: @Murplyx: Who said the values were only `true` and `false`? We can't assume that in JS. WRT `!!n`, that was the point of my last comment... `!A != !B` is the same as `!!A != !!B`, which provide the XOR behavior.

Answer (score 19):

```
if (A || B) { do something }
```

Answer (score 17):

[Use the `||` operator](http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsoprOr.htm).

Answer (score 13):

`||` is the or operator.

```
if(A || B){ do something }
```

Answer (score 6):

here is my example:

```
if(userAnswer==="Yes"||"yes"||"YeS"){
 console.log("Too Bad!");   
}
```

This says that if the answer is Yes yes or YeS than the same thing will happen

Comment: Does your answer improve upon any existing answer? It's a specific use case?

Comment: Is it work? I code like that but it's syntax error. I code like this.
`if (name === 'Jam' || name === 'Jem' || name == 'Jum')`

Comment: Yes, I discovered the hard way that you have to include each statement separately. I worked out that `if (number === 1||2||3)` is like `while (true)`; the second and third conditions ask if 2 is 2 and/or 3 is 3. They always resolve as true to the statement always passes. There goes my plan to reduce the character count. Keeping the statements in parenthesis does make it easier to read though.

Comment: Just much better to use .toLowerCase() instead of having to check all different case variants.

Comment: var choice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?").toLowerCase();

if (userChoice != ("paper"||"rock"||"scissors")) {
    console.log("Invalid Choice made");
}

Comment: doesn't make any sense to write `"Yes"||"yes"||"YeS"`... I can't understand what is your intention.

Comment: This is not correct.

Answer (score 4):

One can use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), too:

```js
var thingToTest = "B";
if (/A|B/.test(thingToTest)) alert("Do something!")
```

Here's an example of regular expressions in general:

```js
var myString = "This is my search subject"
if (/my/.test(myString)) alert("Do something here!")
```

This will look for "my" within the variable "myString".  You can substitute a string directly in place of the "myString" variable.

As an added bonus you can add the case insensitive "i" and the global "g" to the search as well.

```js
var myString = "This is my search subject"
if (/my/ig.test(myString)) alert("Do something here");
```

Comment: Interesting. Documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to filter an IF statement when *condition1* equals 'something' AND *condition2* equals 'another thing' OR 'something else'. You can do this by placing *condition2* in another set of brackets eg...

```
if (condition1 === 'x' && (condition2 === 'y' || condition2 === 'z')) {
    console.log('do whatever')
}
```

If *condition2* is **NOT** in it's own brackets then *condition1* has to be x AND *condition2* has to be y for the function to trigger...

... but it will also trigger if *condition2* is z, regardless of what *condition1* is. Which may be okay depending on your use case, but something to be mindful of.