# Javascript if this OR this statement - second condition ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have to show different divs based on what search terms are entered into my site. The URL will contain the search term entered, so I thought I could check for the string in the URL and show the div if there is a match.

For the Doufeu/doufeu part, the div will only show based on the first term.  The code is below - it will only show if Doufeu is in the string, but not doufeu.  Why?

Based on what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363840/how-to-use-or-condition-in-a-javascript-if-statement) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088098/in-javascript-what-does-it-mean-when-there-is-a-logical-operator-in-a-variable), I have tried the code below, and also using && instead of || because the second link explains the second condition is only read if the first one is false. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263975/jquery-or-selector) and also tried separating with a comma. None work for me though. Here is where I am now:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            if ((window.location.href.indexOf("searchTerm=Doufeu" || "searchTerm=doufeu") > -1)){
            $("#learn-doufeu").show();
        }

        else {
            $("#ci-guide").show();
        }
        });
        </script>
```

I know I could make a new if else condition and separate Doufeu from doufeu that way but surely there is a way to do it with OR.

Comment: If someone types "SeARchTerM=DouFeu" - should `$("#learn-doufeu")` be shown as well?

Comment: No, just capital and lowercase D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are `or`-ing two strings together, rather than the results of `indexOf`.  Do two separate calls instead:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("searchTerm=Doufeu") != -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("searchTerm=doufeu") != -1)
```

Possible a better way to do this would be to use a regular expression.

```
if (/searchTerm=[Dd]oufeu/.test(window.location.href)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Also note that `||` on two strings just evaluates to the first truthy string, so `"searchTerm=Doufeu" || "searchTerm=doufeu"` is the ***exact*** same as just `"searchTerm=Doufeu"` in Javascript.

Comment: ooops you typed faster! and +1 for the regex (and I'd like to vote again because you didn't use `/searchterm=doufeu/i`

Comment: Thanks, this is a great working solution and your explanation helped me learn something new. I used the regex as I think that is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

your code does not reflect your intentions. Your code actually applies the OR operation || to the two strings not to the comparisons.

change the code to

```
if ( (window.location.href.indexOf("searchTerm=Doufeu") > -1) ||
     (window.location.href.indexOf("searchTerm=doufeu") > -1)    ){
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest splitting the conditional statement as follows:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("searchTerm=Doufeu") > -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("searchTerm=doufeu") > -1))
```

This should allow for both comparisons while keeping the check in a single if.