# Only first two if and else if statements are working, others are not. What can I do?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a battery. It only turns `divs` into red and orange, but when it should turn green it doesn't work. I think that only the first two `if`( if (x.value <= 30)) and `else if`(else if (30 < x.value <= 50)) statements are working, others are just not. When I switch, and I put other `else if` statements I the first `else if` statement's place, it works. What can I do to solve this problem?

```js
function changeColor() {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName("battery");
  var x = document.getElementById("range");

  if (x.value <= 30) {
    a[3].style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
    a[2].style.backgroundColor = "";
    a[1].style.backgroundColor = "";
    a[0].style.backgroundColor = "";
  } else if (30 < x.value <= 50) {
    a[3].style.backgroundColor = "#ff6600";
    a[2].style.backgroundColor = "#ff6600";
    a[1].style.backgroundColor = "";
    a[0].style.backgroundColor = "";
  } else if (50 < x.value <= 80) {
    a[3].style.backgroundColor = "#00cc00";
    a[2].style.backgroundColor = "#00cc00";
    a[1].style.backgroundColor = "#00cc00";
    a[0].style.backgroundColor = "";
  } else if (x.value === 0) {
    a.style.backgroundColor = "";
  } else {
    a[3].style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
    a[2].style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
    a[1].style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
    a[0].style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
  }
}

var slider = document.getElementById("range");
var y = document.getElementById("out");
y.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  y.innerHTML = this.value + "%";
}
```

```css
.battery {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

#out {
  width: 130px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.allbattery {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="allbattery">
    <div class="battery"></div>
    <div class="battery"></div>
    <div class="battery"></div>
    <div class="battery"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="out"></div>
  <input type="range" name="" id="range" onchange="changeColor()" value="0">
</div>
```

Comment: `30 < x.value <= 50` does not do what you think it does. Use `30 < x.value && x.value <= 50` instead.

Comment: @luk2302 good catch

Comment: The check with x.value === 0 is redundant, the very first if already covers that case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use OR condition in a JavaScript IF statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363840/how-to-use-or-condition-in-a-javascript-if-statement)

Answer (score 0):

The comparison is wrong. You need to write `30 < x.value && x.value <= 50` instead of `30 < x.value <= 50`

When you write `30 < x.value <= 50` it evaluates the following way,

First it will evaluate if `30<x.value`.
Lets say that value is saved in a variable `res`. `res = 30 <x.value`.

Now it will check if res <= 50. Here everything will be true. The value in res doesn't matter. As res can only be true or false. It will evaluate to 1 and 0 when comparing with 50 and it will always be true. Hence it seems the first 2 if-else block is working.

```js
function changeColor() {
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName("battery");
    var x = document.getElementById("range");

    if (x.value <= 30) {
        a[3].style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
        a[2].style.backgroundColor = "";
        a[1].style.backgroundColor = "";
        a[0].style.backgroundColor = "";
    } else if (x.value > 30 && x.value <= 50) {
        a[3].style.backgroundColor = "#ff6600";
        a[2].style.backgroundColor = "#ff6600";
        a[1].style.backgroundColor = "";
        a[0].style.backgroundColor = "";
    } else if (x.value > 50 && x.value <= 80) {
        a[3].style.backgroundColor = "#00cc00";
        a[2].style.backgroundColor = "#00cc00";
        a[1].style.backgroundColor = "#00cc00";
        a[0].style.backgroundColor = "";
    } else if (x.value === 0) {
        a.style.backgroundColor = "";
    } else {
        a[3].style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
        a[2].style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
        a[1].style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
        a[0].style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
    }
}

var slider = document.getElementById("range");
var y = document.getElementById("out");
y.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function () {
    y.innerHTML = this.value + "%";
}
```

```css
.battery{
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
#out{
    width: 130px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center; 
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.allbattery{
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/davaleba2.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
    <div class="allbattery">

    <div class="battery"></div>
    <div class="battery"></div>
    <div class="battery"></div>
    <div class="battery"></div>
 
    </div>

    <div id="out"></div>

    <input type="range" name="" id="range"  onchange="changeColor()" value="0" >
    
   
    </div>

    <script src="js/davaleba2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's bit funny. JS is not math-based format language. Look at the correct format within `if, else if`.

There is no such `a<x<b` syntax. You should use `&&` and `||` in these cases.
So for example, `a<x<b` is basically `x>a && x<b`
And `x<9 or x>20` is `x<9 || x>20`

```js
function changeColor() {
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName("battery");
    var x = document.getElementById("range");

    if (x.value <= 30) {
        a[3].style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
        a[2].style.backgroundColor = "";
        a[1].style.backgroundColor = "";
        a[0].style.backgroundColor = "";
    } else if (x.value > 30 && x.value <= 50) {
        a[3].style.backgroundColor = "#ff6600";
        a[2].style.backgroundColor = "#ff6600";
        a[1].style.backgroundColor = "";
        a[0].style.backgroundColor = "";
    } else if (x.value > 50 && x.value <= 80) {
        a[3].style.backgroundColor = "#00cc00";
        a[2].style.backgroundColor = "#00cc00";
        a[1].style.backgroundColor = "#00cc00";
        a[0].style.backgroundColor = "";
    } else if (x.value === 0) {
        a.style.backgroundColor = "";
    } else {
        a[3].style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
        a[2].style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
        a[1].style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
        a[0].style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
    }
}

var slider = document.getElementById("range");
var y = document.getElementById("out");
y.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function () {
    y.innerHTML = this.value + "%";
}
```

```css
.battery{
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
#out{
    width: 130px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center; 
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.allbattery{
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/davaleba2.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
    <div class="allbattery">

    <div class="battery"></div>
    <div class="battery"></div>
    <div class="battery"></div>
    <div class="battery"></div>
 
    </div>

    <div id="out"></div>

    <input type="range" name="" id="range"  onchange="changeColor()" value="0" >
    
   
    </div>

    <script src="js/davaleba2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace condition  `else if (30 < x.value <= 50)`  to `else if (x.value > 30 && x.value <= 50)` and so on in `javascript`  there is no any `syntax` like `(30 < x.value <= 50)`

Check below code

```js
function changeColor() {
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName("battery");
    var x = document.getElementById("range");

    if (x.value <= 30) {
        a[3].style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
        a[2].style.backgroundColor = "";
        a[1].style.backgroundColor = "";
        a[0].style.backgroundColor = "";
    } else if (x.value > 30 && x.value <= 50) {
        a[3].style.backgroundColor = "#ff6600";
        a[2].style.backgroundColor = "#ff6600";
        a[1].style.backgroundColor = "";
        a[0].style.backgroundColor = "";
    } else if (x.value > 50 && x.value <= 80) {
        a[3].style.backgroundColor = "#00cc00";
        a[2].style.backgroundColor = "#00cc00";
        a[1].style.backgroundColor = "#00cc00";
        a[0].style.backgroundColor = "";
    } else if (x.value === 0) {
        a.style.backgroundColor = "";
    } else {
        a[3].style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
        a[2].style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
        a[1].style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
        a[0].style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
    }
}

var slider = document.getElementById("range");
var y = document.getElementById("out");
y.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function () {
    y.innerHTML = this.value + "%";
}
```

```css
.battery{
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
#out{
    width: 130px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center; 
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.allbattery{
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/davaleba2.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
    <div class="allbattery">

    <div class="battery"></div>
    <div class="battery"></div>
    <div class="battery"></div>
    <div class="battery"></div>
 
    </div>

    <div id="out"></div>

    <input type="range" name="" id="range"  onchange="changeColor()" value="0" >
    
   
    </div>

    <script src="js/davaleba2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the wrong applications of chained comparisons

```
a < b < c
```

where

```
a < b
```

returns a boolean value

and the second comparison with smaller converts the value to the same type as the right hand side, in this case to a number, you get either/or

```
   true < c    -->    1 < c
  false < c    -->    0 < c
```

The result depends on the value of `c`.

---

Beside that, you could take a cascading style of the comparison and start with the smallest value and go to each greater value.

```
if (x.value === 0) {
    // ...
} else if (x.value <= 30) {
    // ...
} else if (x.value <= 50) {
    // ...
} else if (x.value <= 80) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

```js
function changeColor() {
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName("battery");
    var x = document.getElementById("range");

    if (x.value === 0) {
        a.style.backgroundColor = "";
    } else if (x.value <= 30) {
        a[3].style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
        a[2].style.backgroundColor = "";
        a[1].style.backgroundColor = "";
        a[0].style.backgroundColor = "";
    } else if (x.value <= 50) {
        a[3].style.backgroundColor = "#ff6600";
        a[2].style.backgroundColor = "#ff6600";
        a[1].style.backgroundColor = "";
        a[0].style.backgroundColor = "";
    } else if (x.value <= 80) {
        a[3].style.backgroundColor = "#00cc00";
        a[2].style.backgroundColor = "#00cc00";
        a[1].style.backgroundColor = "#00cc00";
        a[0].style.backgroundColor = "";
    } else {
        a[3].style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
        a[2].style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
        a[1].style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
        a[0].style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
    }
}

var slider = document.getElementById("range");
var y = document.getElementById("out");
y.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function () {
    y.innerHTML = this.value + "%";
}
```

```css
.battery{
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
#out{
    width: 130px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center; 
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.allbattery{
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/davaleba2.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
    <div class="allbattery">

    <div class="battery"></div>
    <div class="battery"></div>
    <div class="battery"></div>
    <div class="battery"></div>
 
    </div>

    <div id="out"></div>

    <input type="range" name="" id="range"  onchange="changeColor()" value="0" >
    
   
    </div>

    <script src="js/davaleba2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution that doesn't use if statements and separates HTML/CSS/JS a bit cleaner. It treats the problems of 1) showing and hiding bars in the battery indicator and 2) choosing the right color separately.

This allows some more flexibility when you adjust the thresholds for each battery bar or if you want to adjust colors. A long series of if conditions is error-prone, so it's better to treat the percentage ranges as "data".

https://codepen.io/timotgl/pen/vYXjWOQ

```js
// Select DOM elements
const battery = document.getElementById('battery');
const bars = document.getElementsByClassName('bar');
const percentageIndicator = document.getElementById('percentage');
const slider = document.getElementById('slider');

// Associate percentage ranges with color names
const colors = [
  [  0,   0, 'empty'],
  [  1,  30, 'low'],
  [ 31,  50, 'medium'],
  [ 51,  80, 'high'],
  [ 81, 100, 'full']
];

const getColor = (percentage) => colors.find(color => {
  const min = color[0];
  const max = color[1];
  return percentage >= min && percentage <= max;
})[2];

// Change handler
const colorBatteryBars = (changeEvent) => {
    const percentage = parseInt(changeEvent.target.value);
    percentageIndicator.innerText = percentage.toString() + "%";
  
    // Show bars within percentage, hide bars outside of percentage
    let minPercentage;
    Array.from(bars).forEach(bar => {
      minPercentage = parseInt(bar.getAttribute('data-min-percentage'));
      bar.style.visibility = percentage >= minPercentage ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    });
  
    // Set the right color
    battery.dataset.color = getColor(percentage);
};

// Attach change handler
slider.addEventListener('change', colorBatteryBars);
```

```css
#battery {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: fit-content;
}

.bar {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

#battery[data-color="empty"] .bar {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#battery[data-color="low"] .bar {
  background-color: red;
}

#battery[data-color="medium"] .bar {
  background-color: #ff6600;
}

#battery[data-color="high"] .bar {
  background-color: #00cc00;
}

#battery[data-color="full"] .bar {
  background-color: #009900;
}

#percentage {
    width: 130px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center; 
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="battery" data-color="empty">
  <div class="bar" data-min-percentage="81"></div>
  <div class="bar" data-min-percentage="51"></div>
  <div class="bar" data-min-percentage="31"></div>
  <div class="bar" data-min-percentage="1"></div>
</div>
<div id="percentage">0%</div>
<input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" />
```